# How to put the asp.net webapi param in body(post) instead of URI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am building a simple api to retrieve the balance of an account from db.It works fine if i append the param to the URI like this

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/api/accounts/balance?accountBalance=DS-00001
```

But when i try to get it from the body using [FromBody] in my action

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("balance")]
    public string GetBalance([FromBody]string accountNumber)
    {
        var data = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetBalance(accountNumber);
        return data;
    }
```

I get this error in postman

> "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
>     "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",
>     "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
>     "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"

I did find vaguely similar to this problem in here but couldnt get through.Saw the tuts in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api but still.Like it said in here for the primitive type to use [FromBody] attribute but still.

And my Route

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("MobileBankingApi", "v1/api/{controller}/{action}");
```

In Postman Body>form-data i entered

> Key = accountBalance                                Value = DS-00001

I want json response as

{"account_number":"CS-0000011","balace":7817.7}

I might be wrong with my postman input or it isnt that i didnt do R&D for this but helping a newbie is still a blessing from you gurus out there.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I saw from the comment you are posting the data as `{ "accountNumber":"DS-10896" }`

To match this in the controller you need to define a object which has a string parameter named accountNumber and read that from the body.

First, define a class

```
public class Account
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then add that as the body parameter

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("balance")]
public string GetBalance([FromBody]Account account)
{
    var data = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetBalance(account.accountNumber);
    return data;
}
```

Then when you post the data use the same json structure as you have now, which would be `{ "accountNumber":"DS-10896" }`

**Update:**

To return an object with the values you requested I would just add a second parameter to the Account class as this

```
public class Account
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
    public int balance { get; set; }
}
```

Then fill the object value in the controller method

```
HttpPost]
[ActionName("balance")]
public IHttpActionResult GetBalance([FromBody]Account account)
{
    account.balance = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetBalance(account.accountNumber);
    return Ok(account);
}
```

*NOTE*: Have a look at the [IHttpActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) which is great feature in web api to determind the response message

Comment: Thank you sir.worked like charm.I got the json response of the balance as "6000".I want the response as {"account_number":"DS-000001","balace":6000}.How to get that?sorry if thats too lame to answer or any links would help.Thank you sir.:)

Comment: @OLDMONK Updated my answer with a solution to your added requirement

Comment: Thank you so much sir.You were a blessing.Thank you once again.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Body type in Postman to send the data as:
`"raw" JSON(application/json)`
rather than `form-data`.

Here's the relevant how-to guide: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Comment: Hello sir..i sent the data like this as "raw" JSON(application/json) {
"accountNumber":"DS-10896"
}
No error but the response is just empty "".

Comment: See the answer from @Marcus-h below, which shows how to correctly match your controller parameterto your JSON object.